# Regex expression for different year formats c#

Tags: c#, regex, expression, builder

So I can have 1 or more years in a string which can be in the format of 2 digits i.e. '18', 4 digits i.e. '2018', full date string i.e. '12/04/2018', or a combination 
Using regex in c# I need to loop through this string to get all values that contain the year in any of these formats and increase it by 1 year.

For example, this string

> "This is a string that has a 2 digit year - 15, a 4 digit year - 2015, and from date 01/01/2015 to date 02/03/2016"

should become

> "This is a string that has a 2 digit year - 16, a 4 digit year - 2016, and from date 01/01/2016 to date 02/03/2017"

Problem with this code is with using the date the index is out of range.
I need a logic that will handle these 3 format years, please. If it contains standalone valid year 2 digits, 4 digits or a date (format dd/mm/yyyy) is the criteria

```
    public string Increment(string text)
    {
        if (text == null) return null;
        var builder = new StringBuilder(text);

        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                builder.Remove(match.Index, match.Length);
                builder.Insert(match.Index, int.Parse(match.Value) + 1);
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Is it just the numbers and dates in the strings that can change? Can the wording change as well?

Comment: no wording, just numbers

Comment: Hopefully Feb 29 is never one of the dates you need to change the year on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex.Replace with MatchEvaluator. Try this code

```
var regex = new Regex("\\b(?<prefix>\\d{2}/\\d{2}/)?(?<year>\\d{2}|\\d{4})\\b");
var result = regex.Replace(text, match => $"{match.Groups["prefix"].Value}{int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value) + 1}");
```

Regular expression contains two groups: optional prefix and year. In MatchEvaluator "year" group parsed to int and incremented by 1

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/obxp1V)